# selecting the id of a child element of a dynamically created link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the id of a `<li>` element that is being created under another dynamic element, an `<a>` tag. I cannot seem to get a handle on the id of `<li>`.  The closest I've got is this:

```
 $("a li:first-child").attr('id');
```

but will only give the id of the first li, not the one that is being clicked.

Here is the script, which I have truncated, because the only the first part is important:

```
$.each(...
    $("#inventoryDiv").append("<ul id='invList'></ul>");                                                
    $("#invList").append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' name='invLink'><li id='" + this.inventory_id + "'>
...
```

and my listener is:

```
$("#inventoryDiv").on('click','a',function(){
    console.log($("a li:first-child").attr('id');
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: invalid HTML - `LI`'s must be the child of the `UL` - you can't have an anchor as a child of the `UL`  Read the Usage context here [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#inventoryDiv").on('click','a',function(){
    console.log($(this).find('li').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need to switch the li and a tags around so your HTML will be valid

```
$("#invList").append("<li id='" + this.inventory_id + "'><a href='javascript:void(0);' name='invLink'>
```

then use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the li's id

```
$("#inventoryDiv").on('click','a',function(){
    $(this).closest('li').prop('id');
});
```

Another issue you'll run into is that ALL your UL's are going to have the same ID - which is also invalid as `ID`'s are supposed to be unique

Comment: The is only UL on the page

Comment: @RobM but it's inside an each loop?

Comment: Yes it is, and although the page is working correctly, your comments have made me notice that there are a few more empty ul on the page.  Since they were empty, I didn't notice, until I looked at the page in chrome dev tools.  Thanks for the spot, and although, it isn't effecting the page RIGHT now, it could in the future.

Comment: @RobM yeah it will - :)  The each loop must be there for a reason - as there could probably be more than one - also if you have a few empty `ul`'s you probably have extra anchor tags inside the first ul because all the anchors are getting appended to the first UL only - unless that's the expected result then you should probably move the .append('<ul>') outside the each loop

Comment: Thanks again, and good spot.  I have moved that out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#inventoryDiv").on('click','a',function(){
    console.log($(this).find('li').prop('id'));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure out when I should use `attr` or `prop`.

Comment: Take a look through this older question/comments. It has a lot of useful information about the addition of `.prop()` with jQuery 1.6 vs. `.attr()`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr